# is there a way to get discord js to wait for a value sent by a user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

This is the code I got, I want the user to say the word wipe which works but then have it wait for the users response to "how much" and depending on the numeber it will delete that much amount

```
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "wipe" && msg.member.id !== client.user.id) {
        channel.send("how much")
        message.author.send(`${getInteger}`).then
        channel.bulkDelete(`${INTEGER}`)    
        console.log("OOOOO");
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextChannel#awaitMessages()`. Make sure to make the function asynchronous and `await` the promise!

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "wipe" && msg.member.id !== client.user.id) {
    channel.send("how much")
    const INTEGER = await channel.awaitMessages({ filter: (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id, max: 1 })
    channel.bulkDelete(
      parseInt(
        INTEGER.first()
      ) 
    )   
    console.log("OOOOO");

  }
});
```